# Package svg Error

Tags: miktex, inkscape

When i try to compile my document using miktex, i get the following error

```
Package svg Error: File `wind_resistance_coefficients_lng_carriers_svg-tex.pd
f' is missing.

See the svg package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...           
                              
l.26 ...wind_resistance_coefficients_lng_carriers}
```

I have inkscape installed and in the path, but by research i found out that i have to activte -shell-escape, too, but i don't know where and how.
When i place it in the arguments in the configuration, seen in the picture below, i get the error:

```
-shell-escape: unknown option

Sorry, but texify did not succeed.
```

Can someone tell me what i need to do?

[image]